# PostgreSQL: How and Why does the WAL (Write-Ahead Log) Grow?

Tags: postgresql, linux

I have a problem with the growing number of WAL files, and they just keep increasing. How can I influence this? I have already deleted old transactions and unnecessary replication slots, which slightly reduced the number and size of WAL files, but it is still a lot.

Archiving is not enabled.

The PostgreSQL server is a physical server with sufficient disk resources, and there are no bottlenecks. It's just that the number of WAL files keeps increasing and not getting deleted.

Comment: What does it mean to delete old transactions?  Transactions get committed or aborted, not deleted, and that isn't relevant to WAL retention anyway.  Maybe the problem is with the necessary replications slots, not the unnecessary ones.

Comment: How many WAL segments are there, and what is your configuration?